# Add suffix to angular route parameter

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-ui-router, router

Previously i have a route with parameter like this:

```
{ path: 'store/:storeId/.', component: StoreComponent }
```

i'm able to get the parameter value like this, if i navigate to this url **https://localhost/store/kfc/** :

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('storeId')
```

now i need to add a suffix `-store` after store id value, the url will look like this: **https://localhost/store/kfc-store/**

i tried to add -store in the routing configuration like this:

{ path: 'store/:storeId-store/.', component: StoreComponent }

but when i tried to retrieve the storeId value using this code `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('storeId')` , it always return null, except if i add -store like this `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('storeId-store')` , if i do it like that then the `-store` value will be included when i get the value, i want only the storeId, how can i achieve that using the routing configuration?

Comment: You can pass values in data property like below - { path: 'store/:storeId-store/.', component: StoreComponent, data: { storeId: "Your ID"} }

Comment: How about remove `-store` after you get the value from `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('storeId-store')`?